# SwiftUI, Dismiss modal/page from child view

Tags: ios, swiftui, dismiss

I am new to Swift/SwiftUI and want to know how to dismiss modal/page from nested child view.

Firstly, I am calling from Flutter, UIHostingController, then SwiftUI page. (currently showing as modal...)
After Navigating to SwiftUI, I am not able to use @environment data from child view.

Is there any ways for this to work?
thanks in advance.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let controller : FlutterViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel.init(name: "com.example.show", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        channel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call, result) -> Void in
            if call.method == "sample" {
                let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                controller.present(vc, animated: true,completion: nil)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation: Binding<PresentationMode>
    private var childView: ChildView()

    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                childView
                Button(action: {
// This works ************************
                    self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("close")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ChildView.swift**

```
struct ChildView: View{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {
// This won't do anything *********************************
            self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
// nor this↓ **********************************************
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
               @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss;
                dismiss()
                dismiss.callAsFunction()
            }
            }, label: {
                Text("close")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put button in a stack in the second case ?

Comment: If it means ChildView.swift, Yes. It's actually like `Body{ VStack{ AnotherChild{ VStack{ HStack{ Button` but it also does not work.

Answer (score 7):

For iOS 15.0 and above, we can use the new environment value `dismiss`, and for that to work with child view, we should also pass it from the parent view to the child view:

**ContentView.swift**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                ChildView(parentDismiss: dismiss)
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("close")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ChildView.swift**

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    let parentDismiss: DismissAction

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            parentDismiss()
        } label: {
            Text("Close")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you had another NavigationView is your ContentView, the `@Environment(\.presentation)` inside `ChildView` is of a child and not the parent. Basically those two are from completely different Navigation stacks.

In order to still keep NavigationView inside your parent `ContentView`, you need to pass the presentation value from constructor of ChildView instead of environment:

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View{
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                ChildView(parentPresentation: presentation)
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("close")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In child view, use normal property instead of `@Environment`

**ChildView.swift**

```
struct ChildView: View{
    let parentPresentation: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View{
        Button(action: {
            self.parentPresentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss;
                dismiss()
                dismiss.callAsFunction()
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Close")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: work like charm, after lot of spend time works awesome

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out that NavigationView in ContentView.swift caused this issue.
Removing NavigationView, I could dismiss modal page from child view...
But this is not what I intended for :(...

```
    var body: some View{
//        NavigationView{    <--------
            ZStack{
                childView
                Button(action: {
                    self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("close")
                })
            }
//        }
    }
```